# Zsh shows debug information on startup

Tags: shell, arch-linux, zsh

My zsh shell is showing some weird behaviour lately. Every time i start a new 
session these debug information are shown before my prompt:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.utf8
LESS=-R
LOGNAME=username
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/tim
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
OLDPWD=/home/username
PAGER=less
PATH=mypath
PWD=/home/username
SESSION_MANAGER=local/....
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=1
SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass
TERM=screen
TMUX=/tmp/tmux-1000/default,12950,0
TMUX_PANE=%0
USE_EDITOR=vim
VISUAL=vim
VTE_VERSION=4002
WINDOWID=25166382
WINDOWPATH=2
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
ZSH=/home/tim/.oh-my-zsh
```

Unfortunately i cannot recall what i have changed to get this behaviour.
I tried reinstalling, but i kept the config files so the same behaviour occurs. Deleting my zshrc and oh-my-zsh also do not stop the debug information from appearance.

When i switch to bash obviously everything is just fine. Since i like cd-tab and git completion i would prefer to clean up zsh instead of switching back to bash ;) Has anyone some hints what configuration i have to touch?

Comment: It looks like you have an `env` command somewhere in your `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you have `printenv`, `env`, or any other command with similar output in some of your files. Check the following scripts including what is sourced from them:

- `~/.zshrc`, of course.
- `/etc/zsh/zshrc` -- system-wide zshrc (this is how it looks like on my **Debian** guest).
- `~/etc/zshenv` -- I don't know what it does particularly, but it's the only `zsh`-like file in `/etc` on my **Darwin**.

Also check what user are you working as.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey tanks for your answer! I checked the files you mentionend but no sign of any env or printenv command. I am using Arch and i checked all the  config files - if they exist - from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Configuration_files but  also did not find anything. My compdump file  are some  entries like _comps=('env'=_'env', 'printenv'='printenv'). I think these are only global  to local variable assignments, but the closest i found. I am using also for root zsh for example and when i sudo su i get the same output at the beginning.

Comment: @theDrifter, have you tried `echo`ing in different parts of global `zsh` files?

Comment: Found it. Thanks for the trick. It was a lonely `export` in my zshrc. It also appeared for  root because i created a link .... -.-